# Facebook updating profile picture using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Using Selenium WebDriver I'm not able to click on update profile picture in Facebook. The html snippet is:
`<div class="_156p">Update Profile Picture</div>`

How do I locate the element?

Comment: Can you provide the html and code you are trying with?

Answer (score 2):

You can identify element using XPATH by utilizing display text as below:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Update Profile Picture']")).click();
```